# Redirect after deleting a list item

Tags: sharepoint-server, splistitem, event-handlers

I have a requirement wherein I have to redirect the user to the homepage, after a list item is deleted. Right now, the corresponding list is shown after the deletion.

How can I accomplish this?

I tried setting the `properties.RedirectURL` in the `ItemDeleting` event receiver, but it doesn't help.

Comment: where are you deleting the list item? From OOB View? or any custom WebPart?

Answer (score 1):

You can use _currentContext.Response.Redirect as below:

```
    public class TestEventHandler : SPItemEventReceiver
 {
  private readonly HttpContext _currentContext;
  public TestEventHandler()
  {
   _currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
  }
  // Methods
  public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  {
   var url = new StringBuilder("test.aspx");
   string urlRedirect = null;
   bool flag = SPUtility.DetermineRedirectUrl(url.ToString(), SPRedirectFlags.RelativeToLayoutsPage, _currentContext, null, out urlRedirect);
   _currentContext.Response.Redirect(urlRedirect, true);
  }
 }
```

To Read further, please check [this link](http://blog.sharepointalist.com/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-event-receiver-redirect.html)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your problem

Comment: This seems to be working. I have a query though: What effect would the boolean in the Redirect method have, when the redirect statement is the last statement? With the value as true, I got the exception `Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.`, and the item was not deleted(the event didnt complete)

Comment: Didn't got you,if it's working please open a separate question for your next query.

Comment: Your code redirected me alright, but it threw the exception I have mentioned above, and the list item was NOT deleted from the list

Comment: On which line you are getting this error?

Comment: I get the exception here `_currentContext.Response.Redirect(urlRedirect, true);`

Comment: Please use false instead of true and let me know if you still face any problem? false indicates whether execution of current page should terminate.

Comment: When I am using false, I end up in the list, instead of being redirected. If I give only the URL, I still get the exception

Answer (score 0):

you need to use itemDeleted method within the event reciver!

code to use:

```
public override void ItemDeleted(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
     Response.Redirect("http://yourSiteHomepage.co.uk");
}
```

i would say use code below but you cant as there is no httpContext in event reciver so code above should work fine!

```
     SPUtility.Redirect(http://yourSiteHomepage.co.uk, SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, HttpContext.Current);
```

Comment: I am not able to get the `Response` object inside the event receiver.

Comment: try HttpContext.Response.Redirect();